# JavaScript Calculations - Based on certain zones

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum

I am trying to create a simple delivery calculation price based on certain zones within countries.

For example this is the table for working out the price for zones:

[image]

So if the user selects UK Zone 3. and its Going to France Zone 4. The price will be £68

I am struggling how to work out how to do the calculations. I have a JS Fiddle showing the dropdown but not sure how to get the calculations.

```
$("#from").change(function() {
            // foo is the id of the other select box 
            if ($(this).val() == "United Kingdom") {
                $(".uk-zones").show();
            }else{
                $(".uk-zones").hide();
            }

            if ($(this).val() == "Germany") {
                $(".de-zones").show();
            }else{
                $(".de-zones").hide();
            } 

            if ($(this).val() == "France") {
                $(".fr-zones").show();
            }else{
                $(".fr-zones").hide();
            }
        });

        $("#to").change(function() {
            // foo is the id of the other select box 
            if ($(this).val() == "United Kingdom") {
                $(".uk-zones2").show();
            }else{
                $(".uk-zones2").hide();
            } 

            if ($(this).val() == "Germany") {
                $(".de-zones2").show();
            }else{
                $(".de-zones2").hide();
            } 

            if ($(this).val() == "France") {
                $(".fr-zones2").show();
            }else{
                $(".fr-zones2").hide();
            } 

        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/barrycorrigan/vzq8w/

My javascript is not the best. But any help to figure this out would be a great help.

Comment: can you please explain what it is you need a bit better? do u simply want arrays? or a formula?

Comment: Yes of course, sorry about that. A formula on how to get this working would be a great help, or even a start. From the table above you can see that all the prices are fixed prices. So if a user selects Uk Zone 1 and France Zone 2 the cost will be £25.

Comment: I need to get this across to the user via form fields etc. So the fiddle above has the dropdowns + radio buttons working. If thinking the logic would be something like : if #uk_zone1 & #fr_zone2 is selected - cost = £25.